# Merge two pandas dataframes using float index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two `DataFrame`'s having different columns, but I would like to merge them by aligning them on rows. That is, say I have those two dataFrames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(6, 2), index=np.arange(6)*0.1, columns=['a', 'b'])

df1
      a   b
0.0   0   1
0.1   2   3
0.2   4   5
0.3   6   7
0.4   8   9
0.5  10  11

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(4, 2), index=[0.07, 0.21, 0.43, 0.54], columns=['c', 'd'])

df2
      c  d
0.07  0  1
0.21  2  3
0.43  4  5
0.54  6  7
```

I want to merge `df2` with `df1` such that the rows of `df2` are aligned with the nearest neighbor index from `df1. The end result would be:

```
      a   b   c    d
0.0   0   1   NaN  NaN
0.1   2   3   0    1
0.2   4   5   2    3
0.3   6   7   NaN  NaN
0.4   8   9   4    5
0.5  10  11   6    7
```

I appreciate any ideas on how to tackle this efficiently.

Comment: Is `df1` guaranteed to have a row for every 0.1 increment? If so, you could set `df2.index = df2.index.round(1)` and then join directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention close

```
df2.index=[min(df1.index, key=lambda x:abs(x-y)) for y in df2.index]
pd.concat([df1,df2],1)
Out[535]: 
      a   b    c    d
0.0   0   1  NaN  NaN
0.1   2   3  0.0  1.0
0.2   4   5  2.0  3.0
0.3   6   7  NaN  NaN
0.4   8   9  4.0  5.0
0.5  10  11  6.0  7.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Accepted because this answers directly compares the two indices rather than rounding off. However, this does not work if you end up with repeated indices (which looks like it is what I am getting in my real application). I think combined with @Paul H answer it would work, but I couldn't make it. For now I drop duplicates before `pd.concat`.

Answer (score 2):

I would temporarily redefine df2's index to be the rounded versions of it's actual index:

```
merged = (
    df2.assign(idx=np.round(df2.index, 1)) # compute the rounded index
       .reset_index(drop=True)             # drop the existing index 
       .set_index('idx')                   # new, rounded index
       .join(df1, how='right')             # right join 
       .sort_index(axis='columns')         # sort the columns
)
```

And I get:

```
      a   b    c    d
0.0   0   1  NaN  NaN
0.1   2   3  0.0  1.0
0.2   4   5  2.0  3.0
0.3   6   7  NaN  NaN
0.4   8   9  4.0  5.0
0.5  10  11  6.0  7.0
```